# How to write a Python script to kill mongo queries?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, backend, pymongo

How can we write a Python script to kill a mongo query which is running over a given threshold time value. For example :
I have to write a function in Python which kills mongo queries running for more than 15 minutes.

Python script to kill a mongo query which is running over a given threshold time

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I wrote a function to find queries that take time more than the given threshold value. but not sure how to kill these queries

Comment: Please add code which you already have

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [killop](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/) command:

```
 ops = myclient.admin.command('currentOp')['inprog']
 for i in ops:
    myclient.admin.command({ "killOp": 1, "op": i["opid"] })
```